# Query to find first entry for given rows or an empty row

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table which contains orders. There could be multiple rows for any given order id (there is no PK in the table). Each order has a timestamp as well.

I am given list of orders, say that `order1`, `order2` and i want to find **first** entry for these orders (or order with earliest date). If order for given order id doesn't exist, then i want an empty row with just `order_id`.

In this example, lets say `order1` doesn't exist and `order2` has 3 rows (earlier row being `2017-01-01`). The query that i am trying to make should return this

```
order id|  status  | order time | 
order2  | received | 2017-01-01 |
order1  |          |            |
```

I think i would need a subquery to first find all orders for given and then find earliest from it. But i am having hard time understanding and then making that query.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need subquery. Using [window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/window.html) are more efficient for this kind of  cases. Most of the databases support window functions/analytical functions now.

Also, assuming you are searching for the orders given a list, rather than a list of orders in a table, Try the example query below. Here, "test" table contains your order transaction records and the ARRAY will contain the list of orders you are trying to find. You will have to use UNNEST function to convert the array into rows and then find which order ids does not exist in the test table. If you could have the list of orders you want to find in another table, the query  could be written differently.

```
WITH
dataset AS (
  SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5] AS items
)
select order_id, status, order_time from
(
select order_id, status, order_time, row_number() over (partition by order_id order by order_time ) rn
from test
union all
 select orders, null, null, 1 from dataset 
  cross join unnest(items) as t(orders) where orders not in (
      select order_id from test
    )
    )
where rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks. but how would i make sure that this would return an empty row for orders which exist in where clause but don't actually exist in table. For example `order1` in my original question.

Comment: are you given a list of orders to find as string i.e. find the records for order1,order 2 like this? Or you have a table where it has the list of all orders and you have to find against those order numbers whether they have any data or not?

Comment: I will have list of order IDs and the I have to find what is their status. If they don't exist in table then I should get an empty row.